# Is it safe to delete .nuget folder inside my user profile folder?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I used Visual Studio to do some tests but I have already uninstalled it.

Has the ".nuget" folder (under my user profile) been created by Visual Studio and can I safely remove it now?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Yes, the `.nuget` folder is used as a cache for packages downloaded to speed up project restore and compilation. It can safely be removed. Worst case, it will have to download the packages again in the future.

Answer (score 18):

Just to follow up on the answer @jessehouwing gave, here is the official documentation explaining the different package folders and how to manage them via supported tooling:

**[Managing the global packages, cache, and temp folders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders)**